# All about call() usage

Tags: solidity

I know `call()` is used to send transactions, but there many more usage of `call()`. So how `call()` works as external call?

Answer (score 1):

`call()` can be used to send ETH or call a function at the target contract. The generalized way to use it to call a target function is as follows:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = payable(target).call{value: optionalValue, gas: optionalGas}(
  abi.encodeWithSignature(
    "targetFunctionName(..targetFunctionParamTypes)",
    ..targetFunctionParams
  )
)
```

Where:

- `target` is the target contract address containing the target function to call.
- `optionalValue` is the amount of ETH to send to the target (in case you are calling a payable function).
- `optionalGas` is an optional value for gas to pass in to limit how much gas you could spend on the entire call. Note that it is very discouraged to do so, since Ethereum's OPCODE gas costs are subject to change with each upgrade and a future upgrade could render your deployed code unusable due to this gas limit.
- `targetFunctionName(..targetFunctionParamTypes)` represents the target function signature (e.g., `setBondCeiling(address, uint256)`).
- `..targetFunctionParams` represents the parameters to pass into the function call (e.g., `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000C0FFEE, 123456`).
- `success` returns true if the function call succeeds and is not reverted.
- `data` returns any data returned from the function call in case the function call returns any data.

Not that it is not recommended to use `call()` to call functions since it overrides the type checks that come with Solidity, and you would also need to assert that `success` returns `true` since any call errors would not bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

The call function in Solidity is a low level function used to interact with other smart contracts. The call method could be used anytime you want to interact with another contract from your own contract.

**How does the call function work in Solidity?**

The Solidity call function works by taking calldata, which can be zero in the case of a native ETH transfer, and executing that calldata on the intended recipient based on the low-level EVM [opcode CALL](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/).

When data (i.e. the function to be called in recipient smart contract) and gas are provided, the call method is able to use these two to execute functions inside smart contracts.
Eg. The below contract code can send the ether received to the _to address.

```
contract SendEther {
    function sendViaCall(address payable _to) public payable {
    // Call returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
   }
  }
```

This given below code is capable of receiving ether from call.

```
contract ReceiveEther {
    // Function to receive Ether. msg.data must be empty
  receive() external payable {}‍
  
  // Fallback function is called when msg.data is not empty
  fallback() external payable {}‍
  
  function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
   }
  }
```

Eg. with the below code, you can use the allowance status:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = _Token.call(bytes4(sha3 ("allowance(uint256,address)") ), amount, walletAddress)
```

In this way you can call any function that is present in the given token contract or another anonymous contract.